# PSModulePath variable requirements before PowerShell starts

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

WPS = Windows PowerShell
PSC = PowerShell Core

When I started, I had three (3) paths as part of the System environment variable `PSModulePath`.

```
%ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
```

I assume that the install of SQL Server created the last one. But, I removed the first two to see if the PowerShells could find their own way or if they needed them?

```
WPS 5.1 64-bit appears to start ok, but ISE reports an error finding `ISE`.
PSC 6.2 starts ok. There is no ISE.
PSC 7.0 starts ok. There is no ISE.
```

I had to put back the `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` directory into the System environment variable `PSModulePath`. After that, WPS 5.1 and ISE start correctly.

Does WPS 5 -need- the System32 directory in the `PSModulePath` before it starts? I would like to remove it. And, actually, I would like to move the SQL Server directory to a more appropriate location. Is there a better place? I often run `powershell -NoProfile` from .bat file scripts, so I do not think any of the six (6) profile scripts (12 if 32-bit is added) is a good place. What do you suggest?

**Update**

=== start cmd.exe

```
C:>echo %PSModulePath%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\;
```

=== run powershell.exe 5.1.18362.145

```
C:>$Env:PSModulePath
C:\Users\lit\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
```

=== run ise

```
ipmo : The specified module 'ISE' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ ipmo ISE
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (ISE:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Comment: The `system32` location contains a lot of important modules (including critical PowerShell ones), and the `PsModulePath` is how PowerShell finds them.  I can sort of understand the SQL module as it is in a non-standard location, but why would you want to remove the other locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an aside, re:

> PSC 6.2 [7.0] starts ok. There is no ISE.

The ISE is a self-contained executable that *hosts* PowerShell, not the other way around. It can only host *Windows PowerShell*, not PowerShell *Core*, so you cannot use it to develop PowerShell *Core* code.

Re your follow-up question, "Should I expect there to ever be an ISE for PSC, or should I think VS Code is the thing to use?"

Indeed, **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) is the editor to use going forward**: It is capable of targeting both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell Core, and all future development effort will go there.

By contrast, **the Windows PowerShell-only ISE will see no new features**. 
(While .NET Core 3.0 *hypothetically* paves the way for porting the WPF-based ISE to .NET Core, I don't think that will happen.)

---

> WPS 5.1 64-bit appears to start ok, but ISE reports an error finding `ISE`.

**Omitting directory `$env:SYSTEMROOT\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` from `$env:PSModulePath` is ill-advised and results in the following symptoms:**

- Commands from the important system (shipped-with-Windows PowerShell) modules located there are *still executable*, because PowerShell apparently *implicitly* consults this location.
- However, command discovery, tab completion, and *explicit* calls to `Import-Module` by module *name* (as opposed to full path) then stop working:

  - Case in point is the startup behavior of the ISE, which tries to *explicitly* load the `ISE` module (among others) with `ipmo ISE` (`Import- Module`), which fails.
  - That *implicitly* loading the module still works can be verified by simply directly invoking one of its commands, e.g., `New-ISESnippet -?`.

---

**When it comes to determining the effective `$env:PSModulePath` value, the PS editions differ fundamentally:**

Windows PowerShell (WPS) uses complicated rules to determine what directories to *automatically* add to `$env:PSModulePath`; in short:

- The *all-users* module dir., `$env:ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` is *always* automatically added, if your `$env:PSModulePath` value is predefined in the *registry* (by default, it *is* predefined, and set to `$env:SYSTEMROOT\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`).
- The *current-user* module dir. is only added if there's no *user-level* registry definition.
- You can override all registry definitions with a *process-level* value of `$env:PSModulePath` set ad hoc *before* calling `powershell.exe`.

PowerShell Core (WPC):

- completely *ignores* any preexisting *registry-based* definitions of `$env:PSModulePath` and always defines its own list of standard dirs. on startup, comprising the PSC counterparts to the WPS locations *plus WPS' system-module directory*, `$env:SYSTEMROOT\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` (because an increasing number of WPS system modules are also usable from PSC).

  - This unexpected behavior was first reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6850), ...
  - ... which led to [this RFC](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/133), which is still pending as of this writing, with the ultimate resolution not yet decided.
- *injects* a *process-level* value of `$env:PSModulePath` set ad hoc *before* calling `powershell.exe` into its list of standard directories, after the current-user entry - assuming that value *differs* from any registry-based definition.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - If it weren't for the obscure distinction between a registry-based value and a - differing - ad hoc value, PSC's behavior is arguably more sensible: it only allows *adding* to the list of standard dirs. via a preexisting `$env:PSModulePath` environment-variable value, not *replacing* it.
  - Ignoring the registry-based definitions makes sense in that users may have used it to point to directories containing WSM-only modules. If a *different variable name* had been chosen for PSC, however, that problem could have been avoided - and that's indeed a solution being considered in the linked RFC.

---

> I would like to move the SQL Server directory to a more appropriate location. Is there a better place? I often run `powershell -NoProfile` from .bat file scripts

*Without* modifying the registry-based definition of `$env:PSModulePath`:

- The only directory that would work for *both* editions would be `$env:SYSTEMROOT\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`, but given that this directory is for module that ship with WPS, that's not appropriate.
- *Edition-specifically*, you can choose:

  - WPS: `$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`
  - PSC: `$env:ProgramFiles\PowerShell\Modules`

*With* modifying the registry-based definition of `$env:PSModulePath`:

- For WPS, you can modify the machine-level registry definition of `$env:PSModulePath` at `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` (which you can also modify via `sysdm.cpl`, `Advanced` > `Environment Variables...`): *add* your directory of choice to the existing value there.
- Regrettably, as of this writing, that won't work for PSC, because it *ignores* registry-based definitions, as stated.

---

<sup>[1] It seems that the test for difference is sloppily implemented, in that setting an ad hoc value for which a registry-based value is a *prefix* match is considered identical; e.g., if value `c:\modules` is defined in the registry, an ad hoc value of `c:\modules.core` makes PowerShell Core think that the ad hoc value does *not* differ and ignores it.

Aside from that, this selective ignoring of environment-variable values depending on their method of definition is highly obscure.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your, as always, detailed and complete answer. It appears that I need the `System32` directory in the `PSModulePath` variable before starting WPS in order for `ISE` to work. I see that PSC 6 & 7 omit what is in `PSModulePath` when they start. After running `Install-Module -Name SqlServer` I find that nothing is added to `PSModulePath`. I assume it is not needed since it is in the standard user modules directory. Is that correct?

Comment: I think ignoring registry setting is good. There is no "registry" on other platforms which PSC runs on.

Comment: My pleasure, @lit; yes, `Install-Module` only targets standard dirs.: the standard all-users dir. with `-Scope AllUsers` and the standard current-user dirs. with `-Scope CurrentUser` (the default in PSC).

Comment: As for ignoring the registry: true, other platforms have no registry, but they do have environment variables, and using the registry is _the_ official method for defining environment variables _persistently_ in Windows. Note how PSC _does_ respect _process-level_ `$env:PSModulePath` values, but only if they _differ_ from the registry-based definition, which is a highly obscure distinction (that is sloppily implemented to boot - see the footnote I've added).

Comment: @lit: This problem aside, PSC does exhibit sensible behavior in that it _adds_ dirs. from a preexisting `PSModulePath` environment variable to the list of dirs. instead of _overriding_ standard ones.

Comment: In a cmd shell, when I have the SQL Server module path in PSModulePath, starting PSC 6 or 7 creates an Env:PSModulePath which does not contain the SQL Server module path.

Comment: @lit: If that value comes from the _registry_, PSC will ignore it. Try removing it from the registry and setting it in your `cmd` session before invoking PSC.

Comment: I see that removing it from the registry, creating it in cmd.exe shell, starting PSC will -include- it in Env:PSModulePath. I am not sure how to think of this as an improvement. If it is in the registry, omit it. If it is in the current environment, but not in the registry, include it. In what way is this better than just using what is in the PSModulePath variable and never reading the registry?

Comment: @lit, I was just telling you what it takes to make PSC see the SQL Server module path - which is certainly awkward, and owed to PSC's current, problematic behavior. As for a cross-edition solution: Short of appending to `$env:PSModulePath` from the edition-specific `$PROFILE` files - which you (understandably) don't want - I know of no good solution. Perhaps use registry key `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]`, value `AutoRun` to set the env var. on `cmd.exe` startup, but that's another profile of sorts.